# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar el primer resultado en vez del último en jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, botón, while, impresión

Tengo el siguiente código que funciona, pero solamente quiero que se muestre el primer resultado en vez del último con *.html* o el listado con *.append*.

```
$("#btnIngresar").click(determinarMultiplo);
function determinarMultiplo(){
    let num1 = Number($("#txtNum1").val());
    let num2 = Number($("#txtNum2").val());
    while(num1 <= num2){
        //console.log(num1);
        if(num1 % 4 === 0 && num1 % 6 === 0){ // num1 = 1 y num2 = 50
            console.log(num1); // resultados: 12, 24, 36, 48
            $("#pResultado").html(num1); // resultado: 48
        }
        num1++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo debes hacer un break del ciclo apenas se cumpla tu condicion para poder mostrar el primero:

```
while(num1 <= num2){
    //console.log(num1);
    if(num1 % 4 === 0 && num1 % 6 === 0){ // num1 = 1 y num2 = 50
        console.log(num1); // resultados: 12, 24, 36, 48
        $("#pResultado").html(num1); // resultado: 48
        //Fijate en el break.
        break;
    }
    num1++;
}
```

Lo que ocurre es que estas cambiando el valor de `$("#pResultado")` en cada iteración por la ultima coincidencia, pero lo que realmente deseas es solo la primera coincidencia, así que para eso paramos el ciclo en la primera vez que se ejecuta.

Otra opcion es simplemente no parar el ciclo (lo cual dadas ciertas condiciones es peligroso), y en vez de pararlo lo que hacemos es guardar el primer registro, el cual sera el que sera mostrado como valor:

```
$("#btnIngresar").click(determinarMultiplo);
function determinarMultiplo(){
    let num1 = Number($("#txtNum1").val());
    let num2 = Number($("#txtNum2").val());

    let primero;
    while(num1 <= num2){
        //console.log(num1);
        if(num1 % 4 === 0 && num1 % 6 === 0){ // num1 = 1 y num2 = 50
            console.log(num1); // resultados: 12, 24, 36, 48
            $("#pResultado").html(!primero ? num1 : primero); // resultado: 48
            primero = !primero ? num1 : primero;
        }
        num1++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aunque el valor ciertamente puede llegar a cambiar, si tenemos un inicio y fin del rango de valores determinado, entonces podríamos establecer dentro del condicional un `if` secundario que valide si el valor de `num1` es igual a 12 y en caso afirmativo asigne el valor al elemento HTML.

```
$("#btnIngresar").click(determinarMultiplo);
function determinarMultiplo(){
    let num1 = Number($("#txtNum1").val());
    let num2 = Number($("#txtNum2").val());
    while(num1 <= num2){
        //console.log(num1);
        if(num1 % 4 === 0 && num1 % 6 === 0){ // num1 = 1 y num2 = 50
            if(num1 === 12) {
                $("#pResultado").html(num1); // resultado: 12
            }
        }
        num1++;
    }
}
```